# Concat Program, Weird symbols

Tags: c++, concatenation

I am following the 'C++ for Dummies' section on concatenating strings. However, my program below outputs the two strings concatenated but with a load of weird symbols in the middle.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void concatString(char szTarget[], const char szSource[]);

int main()
{
    //read first string
    char szString1[128];
    cout << "Enter string #1";
    cin.getline(szString1, 128);

    //second string
    char szString2[128];
    cout << "Enter string #2";
    cin.getline(szString2, 128);

    //concat - onto first
    concatString(szString1, " - ");

    //concat source onto target
    concatString(szString1, szString2);

    //display
    cout << "\n" << szString1 << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

//concat source string onto the end of the target string

void concatString(char szTarget[], const char szSource[])
{
    //find end of the target string
    int targetIndex = 0;
    while(szTarget[targetIndex])
    {
        targetIndex++;
    }

    //attach the source string onto the end of the first
    int sourceIndex = 0;

    while(szSource[sourceIndex])
    {
        szTarget[targetIndex] = szSource[sourceIndex];
        targetIndex++;
        sourceIndex++;
    }

    //attach terminating null
    szTarget[targetIndex] = '/0';
}
```

The output appears as

Enter string #1hello
Enter string #2world

hello - 0╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Óu¬ñ°'world0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I guess the "Dummies" book didn't tell you that the proper #include for C-style string functions is `<cstring>`, not `<string>`.  Also, your code is flawed in a few ways, where all of those flaws are cleared up by **not** using char arrays, and instead, using `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's here:

```
//attach terminating null
szTarget[targetIndex] = '/0';
```

The character literal should be `'\0'`.  The notation's a backslash followed by one to three octal digits: that creates a character with the encoded value.  `char(0)` == `\0` is the ASCII NUL character used to delimited "C-style" aka ASCIIZ character strings.

The way this actually allows the observed output (and note that the behaviour is undefined and you might not see that output consistently) is that...

```
concatString(szString1, " - ");
```

...leaves `szString1` containing `hello -` followed by '/0' which is an invalid character literal but seems to have been treated as a '0' by your compiler, then by whatever other garbage happened to be in the stack where `szString1` was allocated.  The next `concatString` call will try to find the first NUL in that memory before appending `"world"` to it, and that "first NUL" is evidently after `0╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Óu¬ñ°`.  Then the buffer with that and `world` is itself followed by the `0` and still left unterminated.  When you finally call `cout << "\n" << szString1 << endl;` it outputs all that and whatever other garbage it finds until it hits a NUL, but from the output it looks like that happened immediately after the `world0`.

(I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn about an invalid character literal: did you enable all the warnings you could?)

Comment: It'll be somewhere in the project / compiler or buld settings, or turned up quickly by google.